# How to use CSS3 orphans and widows properties with xhtmlrenderer (flying saucer) R8?

Tags: java, pdf, xhtmlrenderer

I read in [this bugfix description](http://java.net/jira/browse/XHTMLRENDERER-168) that xhtmlrenderer should support the "orphans" and "widows" properties of CSS3 since Version R5.
Using R8, it seems not to work.

```
div.textContent {
    orphans: 5;
    widows: 3;
}
```

But it looks like this:

[image: Wrong paragraph breaking]

The paragraph (a div block element) is broken into two pieces although it must not.

Any ideas or experience with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in the Flying Saucer (xhtmlrenderer). There is a `satisfyWidowsAndOrphans` function in `BlockBox.java`, but it is called only after `isNeedPageClear` is called. I've created an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/issues/detail?id=118) in the issue tracker.

Note that the `page-break-inside: avoid;` css rule works.

Comment: I assume this is the answer. Thank you for the page-brake-inside hint, maybe i will apply it to `<p>` in certain circumstances.